# Why is print listed as a builtin?

Tags: python, python-2.7

While reading through the objects listed under `dir(__builtins__)` in python2.7 I noticed that the [keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) `print` is there.

Now under python3.5 I can see that `print` and `exec` are now objects.

What is the reasoning for this?  Why even list it under `__builtins__` to begin with?  Specifically this keyword in particular, what difference would it have made if it were never grouped in there at all.  It seems `import` might have a case for being listed there as well?

Comment: Why would `lambda`, `import` and `global` need to be listed as builtins? They are not objects in Python 2.7. `print` is both a statement and a function, for transition purposes; you can disable the statement to expose the function.

Comment: @Robᵩ I edited to reflect this, while comparing for `print` I had both 3.5 and 2.7 open and threw `exec` in by mistake.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not `lambda` so much as `import` and `global` being able to be objects.  For me this might be a why aren't `print`, `import`, and `global` objects in 2.7?

Comment: They are not objects. What functionality would they offer if they were? Are you confusing the `global` and `import` keywords with the global namespace of a module perhaps? For that you need to look at the module objects stored in `sys.modules`.

Comment: As a language construct, `import` for instance would hold up as a standalone function/object rather than a keyword that is used as flow-control or some identifier?  There already is a magic method for `__import__` would this not be the equivalence of having `__str__` to `str()` for objects?

Comment: But `import` doesn't act on a specific object. `str()` and `len()` do.

Comment: @tijko: `global` has to change the name resolution, which it couldn't do as a function. `__import__` exists, but there's not really any reason to make `import` a function. `import numpy` is a lot nicer than `numpy = import('numpy')`, and `from itertools import combinations, product` is a lot nicer than `itertools = import('itertools'); combinations = itertools.combinations; product = itertools.product`.

Comment: @user2357112 as you were commenting I was removing `global`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print` is in `__builtins__` because there really is a `print` built-in function. If you do `from __future__ import print_function`, the `print` keyword is disabled and `print` refers to the built-in.

`exec` and `import` are not in `__builtins__`. You most likely mixed them up with the built-in functions `eval` and `__import__`.

As an aside: don't use `__builtins__`. It's an implementation detail, and its value is different in different contexts. If you want the module containing all built-in names, use `import __builtin__`, or `import builtins` in Python 3.